# Is there a von Neumann type theorem for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all the eigenfunctions?

Tags: intuition, ergodic-theory, motivation

## Defintions

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu, T)$ be a measure preserving system.
Let $U_T:L^2_\mu\to L^2_\mu$ be the associated Koopman operator.
We will write $\mathcal X_0$ to denote the $\sigma$-algebra of all the $T$-invariant sets in $X$.

We say that $\lambda$ in $\mathbb C$ is an **eigenvalue** if there is a nonzero $f\in L^2_\mu$ such that $U_Tf= \lambda f$. Note that since $U_T$ is an isometry, we must have $|\lambda| = 1$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.
Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we say that $f\in L^2_\mu$ is an **eigenfunction** corresponding to $\lambda$ if $U_Tf=\lambda f$.

It can be checked that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all the eigenfunctions corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is same as $\mathcal X_0$.
Let us write $\mathcal X_1$ to denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of *all* the eigenfunctions.
Clearly, $\mathcal X_0\subseteq \mathcal X_1$.

For each $N\geq 1$ define an operator $A_N:L^2_\mu\to L^2_\mu$ by writing
$$A_Nf = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}U_T^nf$$
Von Neumann ergodic theorem says that $A_N$ converges to $\mathbb E[\cdot|\mathcal X_0]$ in the strong operator topology as $N\to \infty$.

In [Lecture 12 of 254A](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/254a-lecture-12-weakly-mixing-systems/), after Exercise 20, Tao defines a map as follows:

Fix $f\in L^2_\mu$ and define, for each $N\geq 1$, a map $S_{N, f}:L^2_\mu\to L^2_\mu$ by writing
$$S_{N, f}g = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \langle{g, U_T^nf}\rangle U_T^nf$$
Tao mentions that $S_{N, f}$ converges in the strong topology to an operator $S_f$ with the property that $S_fg$ is an *almost periodic* function, that is, the closure of $\{U_T^n(S_fg):\ n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is a compact subset of $L^2_\mu$. In [Proposition 2 of Lecture 11](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/254a-lecture-11-compact-systems/) Tao shows that if $T$ is $\mu$-ergodic then the almost periodic functions are precisely the $\mathcal X_1$-measurable functions. Thus in the ergodic case $S_fg$ is $\mathcal X_1$-measurable. EDIT: [Corollary 3 in Lecture 12 of 254A](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/254a-lecture-12-weakly-mixing-systems/) says that the 'ergodicity hypothesis' in the last line can be dropped.

## Question

I do not see the motivation for considering the map $S_{N, f}$. Also, from the above discussion, I feel that there must be some more general averaging kind of map $B_N:L^2_\mu\to L^2_\mu$ which converges in the strong operator topology to $\mathbb E[\cdot|\mathcal X_1]$, much like the von Neumann ergodic theorem. Perhaps $S_{N, f}$ is an avatar of this mythical $B_N$.

Can anybody shed some light. Thanks.

Comment: $f \not \equiv 0$ in defn of eigenfunction. still reading ur post...

Comment: (1) invairant --> invariant. (2) what the heck is $Z_1$?

Comment: also, i dont know what you're asking

Comment: @mathworker21 I like to include the zero functions as eigenfunctions. It does not change anything of substance and I like to think that 'the set of all the eigenfunctions corresponding to a given eigenvalue is a vector space.' I corrected the spelling, thanks. Apologies for putting in $\mathcal Z_1$. I meant $\mathcal X_1$. As for the question, which admiteddly is open ended, I first mention how the limit of an averaging operator produces an $\mathcal X_0$-invariant function (Birkhofff). (contd)

Comment: Tao gives another averaging operator, namely $S_{N, f}$, whose limit produces an $\mathcal X_1$-invariant function. However, I do not see what is the motivation for even considering $S_{N, f}$. The defintion looks strange to me. Also, in the case of Birkhoff, the averaging operators converge in SOT to the operator $\mathbb E[\cdot| \mathcal X_0]$. So I just had a feeling that there may be some sequence of averaging operators which converge in SOT to $\mathbb E[\cdot|\mathcal X_1]$. After all, the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal X_0$ and $\mathcal X_1$ are 'cousins.' (contd)

Comment: Basically I am looking for the 'right home' for the setting. If that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the comments. i don't know if you'll find home. the question of "which sequences of averaging operators converge in SOT to $\mathbb{E}[\cdot | \mathcal{X}_1]$" seems wayyyyyyy too open-ended. idk the motivation for $S_{N,f}g$

Comment: @mathworker21 It is open ended. But I posted it becasue I thought that it might already  be known and someone can point me to it.